# Conversion of time in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have time entered in `Gridview` entered as 05:00 AM CST to 07:00 AM CST. There are are also other time zones `EST`, `JST`, `EDT` . Is it possible to display one more column with `IST` time without entering manually in DB?

Comment: Yes. Just create the column in UI and add required time offset to the CST time.

Comment: @shree.pat18 the problem is I have many timeszines in single column like JST, EST , CST how to it exactly can u explain?

Comment: Please edit your question to add in **ALL** the necessary details.

Comment: @shree.pat18: I have added the point in my question.

Comment: You may want to read about `TimeZone` class - http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+timezone and than convert one value to many time zones.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question you have single column in you GridView that shows different times for some time zones.  I’m guessing that this is based on a field in your database you have been hand editing.

Consider replacing that field with something calculated in your SQL command or Stored Procedure.

You can return a calculated times for several time zones by adding or subtracting hours to/from your CST time in your table.

```
Select cst, DateAdd(Hour, 1 cst) as est, 
DateAdd(Hour, -2, cst) as pst from [yourdatatable]
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don’t have to change all the records in your database.

If you want to get them all into one column you’ll have to convert them to a nvarchar and deal with formatting but it can be done.

```
Select cst, ('est ' + Convert(nvarchar(100), 
DateAdd(Hour, 1 cst), 120) + ' pst ' + 
Convert(nvarchar(100), DateAdd(Hour, -2, cst), 120)) as OtherTimeZones 
from [yourdatatable]
```